# How to do authorization in AWS Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, authorization

I'm developing an application where a user can create an organization. The creator of an organization becomes its administrator and member.

I have an endpont

- `GET /organization/:organizationId/members`

This endpoint should return list of members of an organization.

Requirements:

- Only organization admins can retrieve the list of members.
- If an admin is demoted or removed from the organization, their access should be revoked immediately.

Details:

- I'm using AWS Lambda and API Gateway.
- The endpoint is protected by a Cognito authorizer.
- Data stored in DynamoDB

Currently, I'm thinking to do something like this

```js
// Pseudo-code
async function lambda (params) {
  const requestorId = params.userId;

  // Get user membership
  const isAdmin = await isUserAdminOfOrganization(requestorId); // call to DynamoDB

  // Check if user is an admin
  if (!isAdmin) { 
   // If no, return unathorized response
   throw Unathorized()
  }

  // If yes, get members...
  const membersList = await getMembersList() // call to DynamoDB

  // ...and return
  return membersList
}
```

Question:
Is there a more efficient, AWS-native way to handle this type of authorization?

Comment: Are you storing roles / org admin settings for users in Cognito or DynamoDB?

Comment: Currently in DynamoDB. Are there any alternatives?